# How to add validation to existing google form items via script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to add validation, specifically text validation, for my google form text items.

However, it looks to me like the `'setValidation()'` function only works with items with known type like `TextItem`.

To my understanding, if I pull a form item via `'getItemById()'`, I would get a generic item. It still has 'TEXT' type but google script just doesn't see it as a TextItem and therefore the `'setValidation()`' function is not available for it.

I have tried doing thing like `.asTextItem()` with no luck. Here is an example script that fails to run because of an error

> 'TypeError: Cannot find function setValidation in object Item. (line
>   10, file "Code")' on line 9.

```
function validationTest() {
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .requireNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0)
    .requireWholeNumber();
  for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
    items[i].asTextItem();
    items[i].setValidation(textValidation);
  };
}
```

So, is there a known solution or workaround for this issue? Thank you in advance.

SC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `.build()` at the end of your validation builder, as it's shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation).

Also, `asTextItem` should be called simultaneously with `setValidation`:

```
function validationTest() {
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .requireNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0)
    .requireWholeNumber()
    .build();
  for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
    items[i].asTextItem().setValidation(textValidation);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `.asTextItem().setValidation()` seems to clear the problem for me. I didn't know it can be done that easily. Could you clarify why (and when) `.build()` is necessary? As I don't see it in the [example I followed.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder)

Comment: @PoonChotchatchawankul yes, I saw that the other example in the docs does not have `build()` and I'm really not sure why two different approaches are shown (and seem to be working in your case). When I test it, it doesn't work without `build()` due to `Cannot find method setValidation(TextValidationBuilder)` error. Maybe someone else can shed more light on this.

Comment: I am so happy to find this :)   Today I am finding this as 2 separate issues --- I am trying to create validation on a new item with a re-used variable...  it didn't allow .asTextItem() ;  it needed .build().   Maybe you can update your answer to address the difference more...  is .build() necessary because we used multiple defining methods ?

Comment: @MikeM double checked but in my case it looks like `build()` is necessary in all cases: it doesn't work without `build()` even when there's only one defining mehtod. I'm inclined to think it's an error in docs. Sent feedback to them, maybe sth will change :)

Comment: @achange--It's a great catch that you found it...  yes, it's certainly not in the documentation